# Producing the same output multiple times

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

This is obviously a minimal example, but with heavier code, it can be timely and clutters my code when I have to effectively write out three of the same outputs, but with each one filtered to represent the three tab names.

Is there a more efficient way to produce this results where I do not have to write out three separate `renderTable` statements?

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("Tony","Tony","Tony","Tony","Tony","Alex","Alex","Alex","Alex","Alex","Jen","Jen","Jen","Jen","Jen"), 
                     sales = c(13L, 17L, 20L, 30L, 38L, 24L, 10L, 1L, 14L, 43L, 21L, 6L, 14L, 17L, 12L), 
                     leads = c(63L, 91L, 51L, 81L, 88L, 97L, 77L, 61L, 74L, 87L, 74L, 68L, 56L, 53L, 63L)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(navlistPanel("Test",
                  tabPanel("Tony",
                           tableOutput("t1")),
                  tabPanel("Alex",
                           tableOutput("t2")),
                  tabPanel("Jen",
                           tableOutput("t3"))))

server <- function(input,output,session){
output$t1 <- renderTable({df%>%filter(id=='Tony')})
output$t2 <- renderTable({df%>%filter(id=='Alex')})
output$t3 <- renderTable({df%>%filter(id=='Jen')})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sapply:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("Tony","Tony","Tony","Tony","Tony","Alex","Alex","Alex","Alex","Alex","Jen","Jen","Jen","Jen","Jen"),
                     sales = c(13L, 17L, 20L, 30L, 38L, 24L, 10L, 1L, 14L, 43L, 21L, 6L, 14L, 17L, 12L),
                     leads = c(63L, 91L, 51L, 81L, 88L, 97L, 77L, 61L, 74L, 87L, 74L, 68L, 56L, 53L, 63L)),
                row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(navlistPanel("Test",
                             tabPanel("Tony",
                                      tableOutput("t1")),
                             tabPanel("Alex",
                                      tableOutput("t2")),
                             tabPanel("Jen",
                                      tableOutput("t3"))))
library(dplyr)
server <- function(input,output,session){
  names <- c("Tony", "Alex", "Jen")
  sapply(1:length(names), function(k) {
    output[[paste0("t", k)]] <- renderTable({df%>%filter(id==names[k])})
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```